# Problems with simultanious MSOnline connections

Tags: c#, asp.net, powershell, iis, office365

We offer a service to our customer by the usage of a website where the user can connect to his O365 account and consult/manage his information. Everything worked fine while testing and so on but when we are "stresstesting it" by connecting with multiple tenants at the same time, IIS (or MSOnline service) is not handling that well and shuts of all sessions. The website is hosted on Azure on a VM where IIS userprofile creates 1 connection to the MSOnline service at a time for 1 user only. We do this because we could not set it up properly to have multiple userprofiles in IIS to create multiple connections to MSOnline service. I have read about Azure App Service Hybrid Connections, where if i understood it properly, we could have the same scenario we have now AND be able to create multiple connections with the multiple "hybrid connections".

My question is, are we doing something that we shouldn't do, is this an issue on IIS level or a limitation of the MSOnline service or something else ? What are our options, what is the best, cleanest and "should do" option ? We are also using Exchange online connection & EWS which we have no issues at all regarding connections.

**EDIT**

Dear community

I don't know wether no one has an answer or if something is not OK from my side is the reason that no one is responding but i would like to update our situation:

we have try to move on and implement a custom Queue system to perform all connection request one by one so they would not interfere with each other however we don’t think this is correct to even try implement this solution. We also tried multithreading/async but this had also some issues and was not a stable solution.

Our code was trying to use threads to do something which should be done in different application domains: "An application domain forms an isolation boundary for security" says the MSDN documentation.

The Office 365 library that we use (the service) to connect through powershell will no doubt use the app domain of the current thread - and we're just using two threads which belong to the same app domain, hence the confusion / failure of our attempt.

We found this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3c4f1xde(v=vs.110).aspx and we think this should be our solution, however we don’t know how to properly implement this and have tried multiple ways but with no positive effect.

We have tried this as well: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/how-to-configure-an-application-domain

And this would be the exact same issue we are having: [Unable to execute two Office 365 commands simultaneously using different accounts in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27938089/unable-to-execute-two-office-365-commands-simultaneously-using-different-account) and was solve for the person who posted the issue by applying the AppDomain “fix”.

Can someone please take us into the right direction, that being how to implement this or directing us to the right direction ?

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have since then been using the AzureAD cmdlets, this allows us not to use the MSOnline service which didn't allow multiple instances for connections, which was the scenario we needed.